# How can I print the values of each duplicate string in a list?

Tags: python

In my list there are multiple duplicates of words.

I want a function that will print each section that includes any type of terracotta as well as it's corresponding number following it. I have been attempting to use `sort()` and `sorted()` but I'm not too sure on how I can manipulate them to do this task.

I'm looking for an output to look like this:

```
[('Gray terracotta', 1880), ("pink terracotta", X), "yellow terracotta", X)...
```

etc. for everything that includes "terracotta".

Here is an example of what I have tried:

```
terracotta_list = [('Gray terracotta', 1880), ('Stripped jungle log', 774), ('Concrete gray', 675), ('Black concrete powder', 596), ('Jungle planks', 535), ('Diorite', 455), ('Polished granite', 363), ('Stone slab (side view)', 296), ('Granite', 264), ('Terracotta', 242), ('Bone block (top view)', 237), ('Dirt', 235), ('terracotta', 11), ('Bone block (side view)', 10), ('Jungle log (crosscut face)', 10), ('Orange concrete powder', 10), ('Acacia planks', 9), ('Sand', 8), ('Cobblestone', 7), ('Green terracotta', 7), ('White concrete powder', 7), ('Dark oak planks', 6), ('Red terracotta', 6), ('Magenta terracotta', 5), ('Orange wool', 5), ('Black oak log', 4), ('White wool', 4), ('Pink concrete', 4), ('Pink terracotta', 2), ('Pink concrete powder', 2), ('Stripped spruce log', 1), ('Chiseled sandstone (side view)', 1)]

list1 = sorted(terracotta_list, key=lambda blocks: blocks[0])

print(list1)
```

As well as:

```py
terracotta_list = [('Gray terracotta', 1880), ('Stripped jungle log', 774), ('Concrete gray', 675), ('Black concrete powder', 596), ('Jungle planks', 535), ('Diorite', 455), ('Polished granite', 363), ('Stone slab (side view)', 296), ('Granite', 264), ('Terracotta', 242), ('Bone block (top view)', 237), ('Dirt', 235), ('terracotta', 11), ('Bone block (side view)', 10), ('Jungle log (crosscut face)', 10), ('Orange concrete powder', 10), ('Acacia planks', 9), ('Sand', 8), ('Cobblestone', 7), ('Green terracotta', 7), ('White concrete powder', 7), ('Dark oak planks', 6), ('Red terracotta', 6), ('Magenta terracotta', 5), ('Orange wool', 5), ('Black oak log', 4), ('White wool', 4), ('Pink concrete', 4), ('Pink terracotta', 2), ('Pink concrete powder', 2), ('Stripped spruce log', 1), ('Chiseled sandstone (side view)', 1)]

def sort_key(blocks):
    return blocks[1]

blocks.sort(key=sort_key, reverse=True)

print(blocks)
```

How can I manipulate or create a key to look for the "terracotta" string in the whole list and print the second corresponding element with it?

Comment: There's a lot of wild backslashes in here, plus some really irregular indentation.

Comment: Are you asking about [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can understand this is what you can do.

```
lst = [('Gray terracotta', 1880), ("pink terracotta", 5), ("yellow terracotta", 8)]
def find_value(lst):
    for tup in lst: # Looping through given list
        if 'terracotta' in tup[0]:  # Checking if string contains substring
            print(tup) # Or you can print
            print(tup[1])
            
find_value(lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) here with a filtering if condition:

```py
import re
print([
    (name, value)
    for name, value in terracotta_list
    if re.search(r"\bterracotta\b", name)
])
```

The [re package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) is used to look for a pattern (the word 'terracotta') using a regex in the name.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this with list comprehension:

```
list1 = []
for k, v in terracotta_list:
    if 'terracotta' in k.lower():
        list1.append([k, v])
```

or

```
list2 = [[k, v] for k, v in terracotta_list if 'terracotta' in k.lower()]
```

They are both the same thing essentially, one is just shorter. I *think* that will get you what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to filter the list for a keyword, not returning the duplicates in the list, as there are none.

The simplest way would be to go through the list and check if the word is contained:

```
for item in terracotta_list:
 if "erracotta" in item[0]:
  print (item)
```

This is a quick and dirty solution, being case insensitive.

Comment: Why "erracota" and not "terracotta"?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Maybe to ignore case, and hope there's no "Perracota"

Comment: @mkrieger1: yes exactly, this is not case sensitive. A quick and dirty solution